# word that goes beyond optimistic?

Tags: single-word-requests

A few months ago my professor mentioned a word that essentially went beyond being optimistic...
He said that optimistic people were simply hopeful, but this adjective that he mentioned meant someone who takes action to make the change that they envision.

I wrote down the word down as meadialistic (that was clearly wrong)
I tried to google so many different ways it could be spelled, but I think I was so off in the spelling that I won't be able to find the answer on my own...
Any help would be appreciated

thank you!

Comment: Idealistic?  "someone who believes that very good things can be achieved, often when this does not seem likely to others"[, according to CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/idealist)

Comment: Did you check a thesaurus?

Comment: Utopian pollyanna? But my vote is for *idealistic* or *idealist*.

Comment: "A super-optimistic history ..." [link](https://io9.gizmodo.com/5833105/a-super-optimistic-history-of-the-near-future-it-all-works-out-okay-really).

Comment: agree with comments - super optimistic

Comment: Sure it's not just "activist" you're looking for?  Whether one is optimistic, idealistic, or whatever, taking action--being an agent--is different from one's view of possibility in the future.  Check activist for synonyms.  People in the arena.

Comment: he did emphasis that this word was uncommonly used...I know none of these are the word... ugh hopefully after finals I will be able to ask him and ill update y'all. Thank you all for attempting to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry and I’ve only been listening for 60 years but never once heard anything like that.

When your professor mentioned a word that went beyond optimistic, can you see the difference between that and optimistic people being simply hopeful, 

Could the adjective he mentioned mean someone took action to make the change they envisioned?

Comment: are ?'s such as 'help me find **the one and only** word' on topic?

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for.  There is something to the idea that an optimist is someone who anticipates that things will turn out well.  I do not agree that it means such a person always passively hopes for the best without taking action.  There are many examples of the word's use in the context of people who take an optimistic view of actions they are about to take.  But exactly in what sense are you thinking of a word for a person who "goes beyond" optimism?  Do you mean someone who generally SUCCEEDS in making things come out for the best?  If not what exactly do you seek?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the answer is bullish. 
Optimism implies **hope** that something will turn out for the best without actually implementing **action** based on that belief, whereas **bullish** implies that one is hopeful/confident to the point that they will place their money (take definitive action) based on that level of hope/confidence.

Answer (score 0):

***proactive***

The OP says:

> ....this adjective that he mentioned meant someone who takes action to
>   make the change that they envision.

**Proactive**, as defined by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proactive)

> acting in anticipation of future problems, needs, or changes

M-W gives several examples, of which this one is the most appropriate to the professor's definition:

> Example: There is an urgent need to shift from a reactive to a
>   proactive approach to health. per kristian hong, STAT, "The 1 percent
>   will continue to get healthier. The 99 percent should, too," 24 Apr.
>   2018

The person who develops proactive policies and approaches to deliver health care effectively and efficiently is beyond optimistic.  She doesn't hope that "they" will solve the problem, but is getting her hands dirty (perhaps literally) to advance a solution herself.

The problem with this answer as an answer to the OP's question is that **proactive** is not at all an uncommon word, but is often used.

Answer (score 0):

This is super late, I can unfortunately not answer your question about "meadialistic" but there is a word that goes beyond optimism- kind of an expression. Panglossian. This is the idea, according to webster-merriam dictionary, that "all is for the best in this best of possible worlds", and is "excessively optimistic".

I've used this a few times in my writing, hope it helps.